# MS Word: How can I precisely set corner radius for rounded rectangle shapes?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have 23 rounded rectangle shapes, each a different size, and I want the corner radius to be the same in each. Ideally, I'd like them to be exactly the same by being able to type in a radius value. Short of that, if there is a trick to getting them close enough to eachother, that would be helpful. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a macro to loop through all the shapes, check if it is a rounded rectangle shape and then set to a specific value (in this example, 0.12 - just change to get the result you want).

Dim shp As Shape

For Each shp In ActiveDocument.Shapes
    If shp.AutoShapeType = 5 Then shp.Adjustments.Item(1) = 0.12
Next